# Why does my environment require I run bundle exec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, gemfile

Whenever I run a rake command (i.e. `rake routes`) I get this error:

```
You have already activated rake 0.9.2.2, but your Gemfile requires rake 0.9.2. Using bundle exec may solve this.
```

If I run `bundle exec rake routes` it works.

I want to be able to simply `rake routes` without having to run `bundle exec rake routes`.

I've looked at other questions with similar errors and tried the various solutions (like running `bundle update`) to no avail.

Also, in my `gemfile` I specified `gem 'rake', '0.9.2'`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Quick update. Recently found this explanation from RailsTutorial regarding the need to use `bundle exec`: "As mentioned briefly in Section 3.2.1, it is necessary in general to prefix commands such as rake or rspec with bundle exec so that the programs run in the exact gem environment specified by the Gemfile. (For technical reasons, the only exception to this is the rails command itself.)" Furthermore, "As long as RVM's version number is 1.11.x or greater, installed gems will automatically be executed in the proper Bundler environment," thus not requiring the `bundle exec` prefix.

Comment: link to the explanation: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#sec-eliminating_bundle_exec

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to execute:

```
gem list
```

You'll probably see a couple of version installed for rake. By the way, `bundle exec` is the **right way** of executing your code in the context of a Rails application. So, you can use an alias for typing less.

Comment: You can also just start off your shell session with `export RUBYOPT=-rbundler/setup`, which is all that `bundle exec` does.

Comment: That gives me: ruby: no such file to load -- bundler/setup (LoadError)

Answer (score 2):

In case if you use rvm. you can try following

```
rvm gem list
```

Answer (score 2):

As @lucapette said, you probably have multiple versions of rake. Assuming you do want to use 0.9.2 you can remove the 0.9.2.2 version to get rid of the warning then run bundle install to ensure you have all the right gem versions for the version you do want (0.9.2 in your case, 0.8.7 in the my example below).

Here are the steps:

```
$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

...
rake (0.9.2.2, 0.8.7)
...

$ gem uninstall rake

Select gem to uninstall:
 1. rake-0.8.7
 2. rake-0.9.2.2
 3. All versions
> 2

You have requested to uninstall the gem:
        rake-0.9.2.2
addressable-2.2.6 depends on [rake (>= 0.7.3)]
...
If you remove this gems, one or more dependencies will not be met.
Continue with Uninstall? [Yn]  Y
Successfully uninstalled rake-0.9.2.2
INFO:  gem "0.9.2.2" is not installed

$ bundle install
```

Answer (score 0):

You may see this message if some of the gems in your gemfile require an older version of Rake to the one you have installed. Perhaps you have updated rake. You can often fix it by updating your gems. Run:

```
bundle update
```

This will update your bundle using the most recent gems in your gemfile. This will likely fix the rake incompatibility.